# Is it possible to find and define a function of these two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions

Suppose that $X,Y$ are random variables, and that I define:

$$
T_1 = \frac{N_1X}{K_1^2}+ \frac{N_2Y}{K_2^2}
$$

and

$$
T_2 = \frac{N_1}{2K_1^2}+ \frac{N_2}{2K_2^2}
$$

where $N_1, N_2, K_2, K_2$ are constants.

I am wondering if it is possible to define a function $f(T_1, T_2)$ such that $f(T_1, T_2) = T_1- XT_2$? It seems that no matter what, I have to define the function to be a function of a random variable, which nullifies it?

Comment: $T_2$ is just a constant, as you have it written. Is that correct? If so, then your expresson $T_`- XT_2$ could be reexpressed in terms of $T_1$ and $Y$. Either way, your initial random variables won't be subbed away using your expressions for the $T$s.

Comment: @DavidSnyder Yes, that is correct, it is just a constant. So it is not possible to do that then?

Comment: Linear algebra says "no".  Basically each of $T_1$, $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent on the other two, and thus so is any constant multiple, such as the second term of your function.